# What is the algorithm used in base_local_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS as base local planner and navfn/NavfnROS as global planner for navigation.

I didn't find the algorithm of these planners anywhere.
In the tutorial of base local planner [base local planner](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner) the information given is not much to understand how the path is planned.
Can anybody please explain how these planners plan path? What is the algorithm they use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259308/what-is-the-algorithm-used-in-base_local_planner/) by [keestu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30035/keestu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoboAssist](https://answers.ros.org/users/30148/roboassist/) on 2017-04-25**:
Would like to join the discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this is not an exact answer, but a useful resource: http://answers.ros.org/question/10718/dwa_planner-vs-base_local_planner/

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0